# New to java script. How to convert my vba custom function to work in sheets using app scriptor

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, customization

I am trying to create my own custom function in Google sheets based on my VBA code but its not working.

```
   Function MyRandBetween(lowint As Long, highint As Long) As Long
        Randomize 
        MyRandBetween = Round(lowint + Rnd() * (highint - lowint), 0)
        End Function
```

Comment: Take a look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: You might mean Google Apps Script (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/), even if it is a variant or similar to JavaScript.

Comment: You might want to show what Javascript code you have already written, and people can figure out what's wrong with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
//  Function MyRandBetween(lowint As Long, highint As Long) As Long
//      Randomize 
//      MyRandBetween = Round(lowint + Rnd() * (highint - lowint), 0)
//       End Function

const getRandom = (low, hi) => {
  return Math.round(low + Math.random() * (hi - low));
  
};

console.log(getRandom(1, 10));
console.log(getRandom(30, 100));
console.log(getRandom(20, 30));
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use Math.random().

Example in Google Sheets:

```
function myFunction() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();   
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('A1').setValue(MyRandBetween(1,100));
}


function MyRandBetween(low, high) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * high) + low;
}
```

Script:

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Works Perfectly. Thanks

Comment: No worries @Abbat if it helps please select as the solution.